# Calling a method in a view controller from a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have to invoke a method present in a view controller who's reference is available in the view. When I try to call the method like any other method, for some reason, iPhone just ignores the call. Can somebody explain as to why this happens and also how can I go about invoking this method?

---

In the view I have this method:

```
-(void) touchesBegan :(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
NSArray* mySubViews = [self subviews];
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    int i = 0;
    for(; i<[mySubViews count]; i++){
        if(CGRectContainsPoint([[mySubViews objectAtIndex:i] frame], [touch locationInView:self])){
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i<[mySubViews count]){
                    // viewController is the reference to the View Controller. 
        [viewController pointToSummary:[touch locationInView:self].y];
        NSLog(@"Helloooooo");
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Whenever the touches event is triggered, Hellooooo gets printed in the console but the method before that is simply ignored

Answer (score 0):

In the view I have this method:

```
-(void) touchesBegan :(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
NSArray* mySubViews = [self subviews];
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    int i = 0;
    for(; i<[mySubViews count]; i++){
        if(CGRectContainsPoint([[mySubViews objectAtIndex:i] frame], [touch locationInView:self])){
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i<[mySubViews count]){
                    // viewController is the reference to the View Controller. 
        [viewController pointToSummary:[touch locationInView:self].y];
        NSLog(@"Helloooooo");
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Whenever the touches event is triggered, Hellooooo gets printed in the console but the method before that is simply ignored

Comment: I copied this up into your question to keep it together.

Comment: Thanks Matt... I am relatively new to this place... :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a view controller for the view and allowed communication between the view controllers. Perhaps this is part of the MVC protocol.

Comment: If this is part of your question, edit the question instead of putting this in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of viewController at the point where it is used to make sure its not nil, use the debugger or add NSLog:

```
[viewController pointToSummary:[touch locationInView:self].y];
NSLog(@"viewController=%@", viewController);
NSLog(@"Helloooooo");
```